# NHibernate - Registration of custom logger factory implementation

Tags: nhibernate

I just wanted to implement an ILoggerFactory to dump only the SQL statements to a file for debug purposes.

I used following configuration to let NHibernate know about my implementation.

```
var configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.SetProperty("nhibernate-logger", "SQLLog.LoggerFactory, SQLLog");
```

Before implementing all the required methods, I wanted to make sure that NHibernate is using my custom implementation.
Therefore, I put a break point in the default constructor of *LoggerFactory* to make sure NHibernate is calling  my custom implementation.
Unfortunately, the break point never get hit.

Can somebody help me on how to configure custom logger for NHibernate and how to make sure that the NHibernate is using my registered LoggerFactory ?

Please note that, I want to do the configuration in code level but not using any *.config files.

Note that I have the NHibernate implementation in a separate assembly and SQL logger implementation in a separate assembly in the same solution.
But both binaries are out put a same bin folder where my main application runs.

```
using System;
using NHibernate;

namespace SQLLog
{
public class LoggerFactory:ILoggerFactory
{

    public LoggerFactory()
    {
        var mn = string.Empty;
    }

    public IInternalLogger LoggerFor(string keyName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IInternalLogger LoggerFor(Type type)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: is the dll SQLLog deployed in the same path of the calling program?

Comment: Hello Felice,
Yes, SQLLog is in the same path as the calling program.

Comment: Is the factory class public? Just tryng to guess: post your code, it may help

Comment: yes the factory class is a public and has a default constrouctor.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the code you wrote is correct. So there should be some subtle missing point. I cheked NH code, and I can say an Exception will be trown if the logger factory class is not found, or not instantiable and so on. So I suggest to do a check list like this:

```
configuration.SetProperty("nhibernate-logger", "NotExistingClass.Logger, NotExistingAsm");
```

And check if you have an exception. If you have, the configuration is done at a proper time, and the fact you are not able to  debug, is due to some misalignment between the running code and the one you are debugging. If no exception throw up, you are configuring to late, or you have a typo in the config key.

Comment: Felice,
Thanks for the update. 
I will check my implementation as you suggested and keep updating the post with my finding.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked nhibernate code and what is missing is the following key on web.config (configuration.SetProperty is not needed):

```
<add key="nhibernate-logger" value="myNamespace.LoggerFactory, myAssemblyName" />
```

Here is the method that uses it (NHibernate.LoggerProvider)

```
    private const string NhibernateLoggerConfKey = "nhibernate-logger";

    private static string GetNhibernateLoggerClass()
    {
        var nhibernateLogger = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Keys.Cast<string>().FirstOrDefault(k => NhibernateLoggerConfKey.Equals(k.ToLowerInvariant()));
        string nhibernateLoggerClass = null;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(nhibernateLogger))
        {
            // look for log4net.dll
            string baseDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            string relativeSearchPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath;
            string binPath = relativeSearchPath == null ? baseDir : Path.Combine(baseDir, relativeSearchPath);
            string log4NetDllPath = binPath == null ? "log4net.dll" : Path.Combine(binPath, "log4net.dll");

            if (File.Exists(log4NetDllPath))
            {
                nhibernateLoggerClass = typeof (Log4NetLoggerFactory).AssemblyQualifiedName;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            nhibernateLoggerClass = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[nhibernateLogger];
        }
        return nhibernateLoggerClass;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In short - **one can not programatically set the nhibernate-logger** (at present). 
One can either add key "nhibernate-logger" or configure *log4net* in app configuration (app.config/web.config) in order to log from NH.

The previous answer has the code. And in short what NH does is:

1. Is there a key named *nhibernate-logger* in AppSettings (think web.config)
2. Yes - try and instantiate the class it points to
3. No - Search for a log4net.dll in the current app and use Log4net for logging (requires standart log4net config)
4. If all fails - no logging

There is an issue for enabling that on [NHibernate](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/issues/917).